# Does Facebook Pixel tracks conversions from subdomain?

Tags: facebook, ads

I have Facebook adverts for Website Conversion. I have configured the URL of the ad to go to mydomain.com. Now, I am trying to capture the conversion events on the subdomain (m.mydomain.com).

Will Facebook be able to track the conversions from my subdomain and show it in the reports?

Is there a specific way in which I need to configure the tracking code on my webpages?